# How can I return Multiple returns in react/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, return

I am wondering how I would be able to return multiple returns from a single return in react/JS. I know technically this is not right and you really should put it into a return object but I am looking for the best syntax in doing so.

I want to return both my div and also the value of my state outside my div.

The state here is **myselectedcatagory**. Separately, I also want to output my **h1 value hello**.

The reason I am doing it like this is I would like to deconstruct my state value out of my function later on down the line in another JS file.

```
     return (
        myselectedcatagory,
        (
<div>
            <h1> Hello</h2>
<div/>
          )}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Is this the rendering of a component?  How should `myselectedcatagory` fit into that rendered JSX?  Or is this some non-component function?  Should this function return an object with two properties, one being `myselectedcatagory` and the other being a JSX element?  Something else?  Please clarify.

Comment: You can return a object from a function, and destructure the properties. What are you trying to accomplish with the above code though? It looks like you are trying to return some JSX? Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are working with and have issue using.

Comment: Overall I am just looking for a way to keep my return (as that is what's painted on the screen) but also want to export my state to be used in other .JS files. Regularly I would just return it then deconstruct it, but since I need a return now, I want to know another way to export just my state.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return both state and elements from a component, just convert the component to a [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
function useMyHookThatReturnsAStateAndAnElement() {
  const myselectedcatagory = 'this is some state'
  const myElement = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h2>
    <div/>
  )

  return [
    myselectedcatagory,
    myElement
  ]
}

function SomeComponent() {
  const [myselectedcatagory, myElement] = useMyHookThatReturnsAStateAndAnElement()

  return (
    <div>
      my state is: {myselectedcatagory}
      and
      my element is: {myElement}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them into another element. If you do not just print and you need it in a higher level component, create the state in the higher level component and just update the state with a function passed as a prop.

```
<>
  {myselectedcatagory}
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h2>
  <div/>
</>
```